# Does whole DOM re-renders if only 1 property in an array of objects set as state changes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am fairly new to React. Here is some of my code:

```
    class App extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);

            const db = [
                    {
                      name: 'xyz',
                      checked: false
                    },
                    {
                      name: 'abc',
                      checked: false
                    },
                    {
                      name: 'yui',
                      checked: false
                    }];

            // Set some state
            this.state = {
                db: db
            };
        }
```

Then I map this.state to show these items into the page.

Now if I change the `checked` property of, say, `abc` (using `this.setState()`) then the whole page gets highlighted in the React Dev tools (blue lines). Is the whole DOM being re rendered or is only that one property's corresponding UI getting re-rendered?

I am guessing since the array stored in the state of the `App` is changing, React sees this as a state change and re-renders the entire `App`. Is it actually so?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it will call your `render` function again. 
If you're calling `this.setState()` in your main `App` component, it basically means the whole `App` component re-renders.